# 'have' keyword for bash completion

Tags: bash, autocomplete

Is `have` a keyword in bash? Or do bash completion scripts use a language that is not bash?

```
have gcc &&
_gcc()
{
```

It is common. See: `grep "have .* &&" /etc/bash_completion.d/*`

I could not find any information on the bash completion tutorials I've seen and I could not find any information in `man bash`. It's also difficult to google "have". Where do I find documentation on this?

I'm guessing it has to do with making sure that there `gcc` exists in the `PATH`?

edit: yes. `/etc/bash_completion` contains:

```
have()
{
    unset -v have
    # Completions for system administrator commands are installed as well in
    # case completion is attempted via `sudo command ...'.
    PATH=$PATH:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin type $1 &>/dev/null &&
    have="yes"
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`have` and `_have` are just two functions defined in the base `bash_completion` file. Between the two, they form a wrapper around the built-in `type` command to determine if a particular command/program available.

```
# This function checks whether we have a given program on the system.
#
_have()
{
    # Completions for system administrator commands are installed as well in
    # case completion is attempted via `sudo command ...'.
    PATH=$PATH:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/sbin type $1 &>/dev/null
}

# Backwards compatibility for compat completions that use have().
# @deprecated should no longer be used; generally not needed with dynamically
#             loaded completions, and _have is suitable for runtime use.
have()
{
    unset -v have
    _have $1 && have=yes
}
```

Comment: Thanks chepner. Now I understand. When bash reads in the completion files if the PATH doesn't have a program then there is no need to keep the completion script in memory so it just skips over it. Makes perfect sense. I'm putting my `have` in my question for reference. I guess I don't have a `_have`. I wonder why.

Comment: I don't know too much about the internals of the bash completion project. I pulled the above code from the [bash-completion `git` repository](http://bash-completion.alioth.debian.org) just this morning; it may be a new direction in development, given the note about `have` being deprecated in favor of `_have`.