# Writing a bash completion script similar to scp

Tags: bash, shell, bash-completion

I have a script I thought I would allow completions via Bash completion.

The script takes a quoted string argument and then a file or server e.g.

```
my_cmd "something"  stuff
```

I thought I could leverage the same completion as the scp command by:

```
have my_cmd &&
_my_cmd()
{
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/scp >/dev/null 2>&1 && complete -F _scp $1 && return 124
} && complete -F _my_cmd my_cmd
```

Which works, however this appends a colon to known servers. Not really knowing much about how the bash-completion works have you any better ideas to accomplish this?

Comment: what's "have" before my_cmd && ?

Comment: have is to make sure the command my_cmd exists see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12874920/have-keyword-for-bash-completion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look in the scp completion, it's using _known_hosts_real from /usr/share/bash-completion/bash-completion:

```
# Helper function for completing _known_hosts.
# This function performs host completion based on ssh's config and known_hosts
# files, as well as hostnames reported by avahi-browse if
# COMP_KNOWN_HOSTS_WITH_AVAHI is set to a non-empty value.  Also hosts from
# HOSTFILE (compgen -A hostname) are added, unless
# COMP_KNOWN_HOSTS_WITH_HOSTFILE is set to an empty value.
# Usage: _known_hosts_real [OPTIONS] CWORD
# Options:  -a             Use aliases
#           -c             Use `:' suffix
#           -F configfile  Use `configfile' for configuration settings
#           -p PREFIX      Use PREFIX
# Return: Completions, starting with CWORD, are added to COMPREPLY[]
```

So, what you probably want is:

```
_my_cmd() {
    local cur prev words cword
    _init_completion || return
   _known_hosts_real -a "$cur"
} && complete -F _my_cmd my_cmd
```

This works for me, at least. I admit, I don't generally write these, but it seems consistent with how other completions work. Here is another related example if you want to do some more shell foo with your completions:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136351/autocomplete-server-names-for-ssh-and-scp

Edited:

Here's for hosts and files, mostly inspired by what `_scp_local_files` does:

```
_my_cmd() {
    local cur prev words cword
    _init_completion || return

   _known_hosts_real -a "$cur"

    COMPREPLY+=( $( ls -aF1dL $cur* 2>/dev/null | \
        sed -e 's/[*@|=]$//g' -e 's/[^\/]$/& /g' -e "s/^/$prefix/") )

} && complete -F _my_cmd my_cmd
```

Again, this is just taking the stuff you want from the `_scp` completion and making your own. This works for me, but the directory name completion is a little wonky.

Comment: Yes that works fine for the servers without the suffix corrently, the reason why I was trying to leverage the scp completion was due to it also completing on filenames.  Do you know how I would merge the multiple rules?  Cheers.

Comment: I see what you mean about the directory completion - it adds a space at the end.  Will see if I can figure out why that is.